# Replacing one percent symbol with two in Python?

Tags: python-2.7

I'm trying to clean up strings containing percent symbols. What I intend do is replace each `%` with `%%`!

When I use `my_string.replace("%", "%%")`, it works out fine in Python 3.
However, when I do the same in Python 2.7 and print the result (using the future print function), it simply prints the original string. I guess this happens, because %% is commonly used to escape the percent symbol in strings?

What would be a viable workaround for Python 2.7? I'm parsing FFmpeg commands, and single percent symbols are forbidden, since FFmpeg uses `%d`to indentify number sequences in filenames of image sequences.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using **python 2.7** this is an example to replace % by %%:

```
import string
str = "replace % "
str = string.replace(str, "%","%%")
print "Result:",str
```

The result is:

```
Result: replace %%
```